# Group by two colums in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I have the following script running in my power bi

```
dataset['Percent_Change'] = dataset.groupby('Contract_Year')['Norm_Price'].pct_change().fillna(0)

dataset['Norm_Change'] = dataset['Percent_Change'].add(1).groupby(dataset['Contract_Year']).cumprod()
```

Initially I only had one location so I just needed it the calculation to run by contract year.
Now I have several locations in the same dataset how do I make the calculation perform the same but for each location and then by contract year?

Field name: [location]

Answer (score 0):

In order to group by several columns, you can just use a list of columns instead of a string.

something like:

```
dataset.groupby(['Contract_Year','Locations'])
```

Comment: I get invalid syntax on the second calculation.

Comment: I need the code to reset the calculation once a new location is encounter and then perform the grouping of the calculation by contract year so for example ---> Start at 1 for every new location and contract year and then perform the calculation same for % change